# bessel function with Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, bessel-functions

I need to prove this:

$$ \mathcal F{\frac{1}{r^2}}\frac{d}{dr}r^2 \frac{dC}{dr}$$

$$= (\frac{2}{\pi})^{1/2} \int_0^\infty\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{d}{dr}r^2\frac{dC}{dr}j_0(kr)r^2dr$$

$$ =-k^2 (\frac{2}{\pi})^{1/2} \int_0^\infty C(r)j_0(kr)r^2dr$$

$$= -k^2 \hat C (k) $$

Note that the $\mathcal F$ is the Fourier Transform.

In step 3 to step 4 I know I need to do integration by parts twice, where I am guessing that :

$$u=r^2 $$
$$ du=2rdr$$

And then we do it again later where:

$$u_2 = 2r $$

$$ du_2 = 2 dr$$

I am not sure what the dv's should be, and the corresponding v.

Normally I would assume that the other term is the dv term, which here would mean:

$$dv = C(r)j_0(kr)$$

But then I have two functions of r.

Please help me understand this problem if you have time.

Comment: Any help guys??